# Azure Application Insights log severity levels

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I am trying to find out what is wrong with my code or approach. I am using Azure Functions (v3) and use ILogger interface to log events from my functions.
Here is the sample code I am using:

```
        [FunctionName("GetVersion")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("[TEST] this is informational");
        log.LogDebug("[TEST] this is debug");
        log.LogTrace("[TEST] this is trace");
        return new OkResult();
    }
```

My Azure Functions have Application Insights are enabled, so logs are written to the traces table, and I can query for them like this:

```
traces 
| order by timestamp
| where operation_Name == 'GetVersion'
| project timestamp,message,severityLevel
| limit 200
```

But the result looks like this (columns are timestamp, message and the last one is log severity level):

[image]

The problems I have are that:

1. Severity both for Trace and Debug logs is 0, while they should have distinct levels.
2. Actual severity levels differ from MS documentation. Trace should be 0 and Debug 1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loglevel?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Expected behavior is that severity in App Insights matches severity levels from documentation.
What am I missing here?

P.S. My host.json looks like this

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Information",
      "Function": "Debug",
      "Function.GetVersion": "Trace",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The severity levels of application insights are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.datacontracts.severitylevel?view=azure-dotnet

"LogDebug" and "LogTrace" from ILogger is "Verbose" for application insights. Therefore, as far as I know, Application insights can not distinguish or filter-out what you log as "LogTrace" and filter-in what you log as "LogDebug".

Comment: It's backwards from the Alert Severity Level when setting up an alert in Azure. Not confusing at all.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the **severityLevel** doesn't show correctly when using `ILogger`. I tried with `TraceWriter`, it works as expected. Here is my testing sample. You can try it instead.

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, TraceWriter  log)
{
    log.Info("101 Azure Function Demo - Basic logging with TraceWriter");
    log.Warning("Here is a warning log message");
    log.Error("Here is an error log message");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    return name != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello11")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

The result

[image]

[image]

Reference:

[Basic logging with TraceWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/logging?tabs=csharp#basic-logging-with-tracewriter)

Comment: Thank you. While this is a workaround to get proper severity level in saved logs, the ILogger is recommended way of logging by MS and it allows for structured logging for App Insights, so I'd like to stay with ILogger way.

Comment: For anyone else landing here TraceWriter is no longer recommended. Probably not even supported anymore (2022, .NET 6).

Answer (score 0):

I wrestled with this issue recently and discovered that I needed to add a additional Logging configuration specifically for ApplicationInsights

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=..."
  }
}
```

You can read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6#how-do-i-customize-ilogger-logs-collection) which states that: *"The default setting for Application Insights is to only capture Warning and more severe logs."*